# Can a virus/ malware still linger if the symptoms of installing the virus are gone after system restoring to an earlier point?

Tags: windows, windows-10, virus, malware

So last night, I downloaded on my Windows 10 PC what I thought was a Minecraft setup file from Kickasstorrents (a mirror site). When I opened it, a window came which said it needed to verify if I am a human and told me to click on a button 'Begin test' which was supposed to give me a password that I would have to submit in that window. I clicked the button and it took me to a webpage. I forgot the exact address but it had the word 'humantest' somewhere in it.

Soon the browser (Chrome) was closed automatically. When I reopened the browser, I found my homepage has been changed to a weird-looking search engine site. My default search engine has also been changed. Furthermore, an extension was installed, which I removed from Chrome promptly.

But there were more symptoms. Porn ads would pop up on my desktop every few seconds. Windows asking me to install some even weirder-looking programs would also come up. Then ta blank window would come up which had the title of something like 'News'.

I was frustrated, because I never installed such a virus (or malware) in my life. But I decided to try a system restore. I restored to a point created the day before.

After the restore was complete, all those ad popups and program installation windows were gone. The only thing that remained was the default search engines on Chrome and I changed that manually.

Is anybody familiar with such viruses/ malware? Is there any chance the virus is still lurking somewhere deep down in my computer and doing nasty things?

(I am reluctant to install an antivirus, because it sometimes uninstalls many Chrome extensions I installed manually (from crx files). Also, they tend to make many other programs dysfunctional as well.)

Thank you very much for taking your valuable time to read such a long post.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, unfortunately there is still a chance that traces of a virus and/or malware will remain after a Windows system restore.  To be honest, the only way to be absolutely sure that your system is clean after an infection is a full wipe/reload of the operating system.

In the interim, at the very least I would run a quick scan with [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/antimalware/).  If it comes up clean, you should have a healthy dose of peace-of-mind for now.  If any symptoms resurface, I would definitely reload the OS.

Comment: Thank you very much. So far no symptoms have resurfaced. This morning my Samsubg touchpad update failed, but it could be just a coincidence, I guess.

Comment: I just ran a Malwarebytes scan and deleted all the evil things it found (somewhere around 5,000.) Will now installing an antivirus be necessary or that should be enough?

Comment: Now there is one problem. Windows 10 language input indicator is disabling itself every time I restart or sign in to my computer. What can I do?

Comment: First of all, I would run an additional Malwarebytes _Threat Scan_ until the results come back clean.  If the initial scan found over 5,000 items, you definitely had something nasty infecting your machine. I utilize Windows Defender and Malwarebytes on my Windows 10 computers without any problems, but I also never visit any Torrent sites.  Honestly, once the scans come back clean it would probably be wise to backup your personal files/folders and then completely wipe and reload Windows 10:  [How to Clean Install Windows 10](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/1950-windows-10-clean-install.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. I currently don't have the time for a setup. I have so much to do within next couple of weeks. So, are there any alternatives? Will installing an antivirus do things that Malwarebytes or adware removal programs couldn't?

Comment: Malwarebytes is arguably the best on-demand scanner to alleviate malware or virus-related problems.  At the same time, it is always wise to have an antivirus program active, whether it is a third-party application or Windows Defender itself.  If you have a compelling need to use your machine throughout the next two weeks, that's fine... but I wouldn't delay the reload any longer than necessary.  We are always glad to help, but please take this as a valuable lesson regarding the inherent risks associated with downloading software from torrent sites.

Comment: Yeah, I'll have to do this. Thank you very much for your help. This will indeed be a lifelong lesson for me.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely still have some trash left in your browsers/registry.

You can try [Adware Removal Tool](http://www.adwareremovaltool.org/) or [AdwCleaner](https://toolslib.net/downloads/viewdownload/1-adwcleaner/). They both clean up browsers, registries, and various things. They're not antivirus apps. They are adware checkers that you run on demand (they don't boot up with Windows). Just make sure to check the things it's deleting before you confirm. It might delete some needed extensions/history/registry items/etc. If you feel one didn't completely remove everything you want gone, there's no harm in running both.

Next time, avoid opening anything with admin privileges and stay away from mirror sites. If any torrent/download/etc website automatically opens a second window, close that immediately. No legitimate content is ever presented as a separate window. It can only be an ad, or a virus. Also, if you browse torrent sites often, only use their legitimate servers. Usually, news will come up if a torrent site domain gets seized. You can easily find which domain they switched to just by searching a bit on Google.

Eventually it all boils down to how good you can identify which the right button is, and which is spam/ad/virus.

---

Disclaimer: I am in no way connected to any of the above programs.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, I just ran AdWare Removal and it removed quite some stuff (it did uninstall HotSpotShield, though, but I reinstalled it right away.)

Comment: And no, I didn't open that link from a second window. I just copied the magnet link. I used this kickass.cd quite a few times before, and no problems occurred. This time it's totally different though. You can check it out yourself. Search 'Minecracft' on that site, and every single results they will show you is a virus/ adware. How do I know? Because they'll show you the number of comments beside each torrent as somewhere above 200+. However, when you actually go to the pages of those individual torrents, you'll see no comments at all.

Comment: Windows 10 language input indicator is disabling itself every time I restart or sign in to my computer. What can I do?

Comment: @user427360 comments really don't work on new kickass domains. The search results page displays the number of comments it *used to have* back when they had their old domain setup. However they haven't fixed the torrent page so all torrent pages won't display any comments.

Most likely you just encountered a bad popup ad, in which case you can simply just try using AdBlock.

Comment: Yeah, it seems you're correct about the comment thing. But no, I didn't encounter a popup ad. Just like I said, I used the magnet link, and ran the exe file. And I DO use Adblock, with all its filters on.

Comment: Oh :/ Then probably it's just the executable that's at fault.

Comment: From the description above (one more thing to add, even after restoring, and running Malwarebytes and the two adware removal programs, my browser would occasionally open techbrowser[dot]com new tabs when I clicked on a random links. After I googled, I learned it can be solved by deleting my Chrome user, and I did just that. That techbrowser virus hasn't reappeared since then), do you think the malware that infected me was a serious one? Like one that can steal my password, credit card numbers, or identity etc? 

Thank you very much for your help once again.

Comment: Oh that's terrible. Although so far from what you've told us, the malware hasn't really done anything that needs admin access. The most it could have gotten is possibly some personal information like email, IP, location, PC name, etc. I don't think it would have accessed credit card info or passwords, unless you have those stored in an unencrypted location or something.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't think it got my email address, because there have been no influx of unusual emails or spams in my account recently. As for saving passwords, yes, I did use Chrome's 'Save password' feature, but those are encrypted, right? Because, if I want to see those passwords, I have to first submit my windows account password.

Comment: Yup, as far as I know all passwords and credit cards saved within Chrome are safe.